# Python3 and pip3 venv: Is there a global environment? Where is it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

## Is there one or more System-wide or User-Account-wide Global Python3 Virtual Environment?

- Is it globally available across the whole Operating System?
- Is it visible only to each individual User Account? (This may depend on *where* on the host OS it lives)

I am trying to understand some basic concepts behind `python3` / `pip3` `venv`s.

Is there a concept of a "system-wide" or "user-account-wide" "global" environment? (venv)

If so, where is that stored?

This question will depend on the type of Operating System. It might be useful to have information about the 3 most common ones (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) here, however for me personally I am using Debian 12 Linux.

---

##### Additional Information (Not part of Primary Question)

This question was propted by the fact that Visual Studio Code shows multiple environments when connected to my remote development host.

As can be seen in the screenshot below, with the *Python Environment Manager Extension* installed, some environments are shown. This includes 2x Workspace environments and another environment called "default_venv".

- I created "default_venv" in a folder called "python3_venv_environments" which lives inside my home directory `~`
- I created a venv with the folder name `.venv` which lives inside the folder which is currently open with VS Code
- VS Code also shows two Global Environments. I do not know what these are, where they are, or why there are two. "Global" and "Venv"

[image: Python Environment Manager Extension VS Code]

Comment: what do you see when you open the `Global` item

Comment: why don't you create an issue at the repo and ask for explanation of the View

Comment: @rioV8 I see a list of two things: `(3.11.2) /bin/python3` and `usr (3.11.2) /usr/bin/python3`. One of these I assume is the system default install location for Python 3. I don't know which is the default, or why the other one is there. Also, these are just paths to a python3 interpreter executable? Is that the same as a venv? I assume not?

Comment: you can install stuff in the installed Python directory and you also select it as your current Python interpreter

Comment: @rioV8 I don't fully understand the last comment, can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

A virtual environment *could be* visible to all users (i.e. "global"), depending on how and where (and why) you create it.  However, that's not the normal approach.

> Is there a concept of a "system-wide" or "user-account-wide" "global" environment? (venv)

Not specifically.

Generally speaking, the idea of a virtual environment is to allow different users, projects or applications to tailor their Python environments differently without interfering with other users, projects or applications.

The "global" python environment is your system's (non-virtual) Python 2.7 and/or Python 3.x installations.  If you wanted to install packages for everyone / everything to use, you would typically add them to those installations using `apt install` or using `pip` or `pip3`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I would guess that, given the recent changes in Debian 12, that the use of a "global" configuration is essentially strongly discoraged, and that everything should be now done with local venvs? `pip3` will complain if one tries to use it to install anything. "externally managed environment"

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Usually, we recommend using a virtual environment, which is helpful for better management of packages. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments